# retrieve status from methods insert or save of MongoDb with Spring Data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I don't know how retrieve or get a status to know it if insert or not a document in MongoDb

```
public boolean save(T usuario) {
    boolean result = false;
    mongoOperations.save(usuario);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to get a `WriteResult` from `save`or `ìnsert`operations.

But what you can do is setting the `WriteConcern` for one or all operations.

`mongoTemplate.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern wc)`

See also the [mongodb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/)